# why don't I need to require 'capybara/rails' in spec_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

According to capybara's [readme](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) on Github I have to require capybara/rails in my **spec_helper** file after installing the gem:

```
require 'capybara/rails'
```

But even if I leave out the require statement in spec_helper, I can still use the following capybara syntax:

```
  scenario "successfully creates a new user account" do
    visit "users#index"
    fill_in "user_email", with: "foo@bar.com"
    click_button "Create User"
    expect(page).to have_content "User successfully created"
  end
```

Does it have something to do with the rails g rspec:install command? I am confused about why the syntax works; how does the app know?

Answer (score 0):

All requiring capybara/rails does is set up Capybara.app and configure the rack-test driver to respect any `data-method` attributes on links.  Other than that it doesn't affect capybara.  If you've already configured Capybara.app some other way then things will work fine.  You may also have it required in your `rails_helper.rb` rather than `spec_helper.rb`